# When to use configureEach

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I've seen many Gradle projects that have this:

```
tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}
```

And I've also seen many Gradle projects containing this:

```
tasks.withType<KotlinCompile>().configureEach {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}
```

Are these the same? If not, what is the difference? When should one of them be used instead of the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `withType<T>` and `withType<T>().configureEach` execute an action on a collection of domain objects<sup>1</sup> of type `T`. However they do so with a difference:

- [`withType()`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/kotlin-dsl/gradle/org.gradle.api/-domain-object-collection/with-type.html), when passed an action as an argument, executes that action immediately, and also executes that action against any domain objects of the specified type subsequently added to the original collection.
- [`configureEach()`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/kotlin-dsl/gradle/org.gradle.api/-domain-object-collection/configure-each.html) executes its action lazily so that the action only runs on a particular domain object when that domain object is requested from the collection.

`withType`, then, is suitable when you want the action to run on all objects of that type on every invocation of the build. You might use it to, say, create a separate task for each object of that type.

`withType().configureEach` is suitable when you only want the action to run for objects of that type when required by an invocation of the build. This is often suitable for tasks, since it is more efficient to avoid configuring tasks that are not required for a given build.

Therefore for `Task` objects, it is normally advisable to use `configureEach` in conjunction with `withType`.

---

<sup>1</sup>In your example, `Task` objects. However it could apply to other domain objects defined by the build, such as compilations.